# Flutter Provider being disposed off when widget is live with AnimatedSwitcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a Flutter app where I am using an AnimatedSwitcher to animate to a different widget on user tap in the same parent widget.
I am using several Providers for the child widget being animated to which are giving errors like : **A Product was used after being disposed**

I am not very experienced with Provider and have used it in the same app with Navigators and never faced a problem.

I am using setState to set the child widget as below :

```
_animateToChild() {
    setState(() {
      childWidget = MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (_) => ModelPath(storePath: AppConstants.carousel)),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Product())
          ],
          child: ChildFragment(
            productRoot: 'My Product',
          ));
    });
  }
```

In Child Fragment widget I access the ModelPath as following and navigate to a different page :

```
_openCollection(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => MultiProvider(providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Provider.of<ModelPath>(context)),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Product()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductSelector())
      ], child: CollectionFragment(title: product.title)),
    ));
  }
```

_openCollection() is called on tapping on one of the buttons on ChildFragment.

Can someone please help me out here as how to use Providers with AnimatedSwitcher ?

My AnimatedSwitcher after I got it working :

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation animation) {
          final inAnimation =
              Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                  .animate(animation);
          final outAnimation =
              Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
                  .animate(animation);

          return SlideTransition(position: inAnimation, child: child);
        } ...)
```

Comment: Usually Multiprovider is used as heo root of your widget tree, so they stay alive while the app is open, of course that if you pop and push your MultiProvider, the providers inside will be disposed and recreated, if you are looking for something more locally you should use something like [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)  or [States Rebuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/states_rebuilder)

Comment: Thank you for responding. i have used MultiProviders in other parts of app where I am using Navigators and have not faced this problem. Here I am using an AnimatedSwitcher to switch to a child widget and then Navigate which is causing problems. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see any AnimatedSwitch in your code, can your post your full code?

Comment: Yes I tried something now and it's working. In AnimatedSwitcher's transitionBuilder I was using my widget stored in local variable instead of the child provided in the callback method itself. I changed it to the child variable and it's working. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Animated widget dispose the current widget and create the new one, so if the current widget has some providers created inside of it  these will be disposed, if you are storing the widget in a variable, the current widget won't be disposed because the Garbage Collector can't remove that widget from the memory .... you are basically keeping your widget alive even if you are not using it anymore

Comment: once a widget is not used, neither referred by anything anymore, the garbage collector will remove the object from memory to clean and release space, that's when your widgets and classes will get disposed.

Comment: But, My widget was being disposed when I was storing it in a local variable called childWidget and using the childWidget var instead of the child var provided by the TransitionBuilder callback. Once I pointed to child var instead of childWidget var it's working. I don't understand why :/. I do not know the internals of AnimatedSwitcher :(